# Lazy loading while adding object to database without loading referenced objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I found examples on how to use lazy loading to add objects to the database without having to load the references objects but I can not seem to string the correct search keywords to find out how to set up my models to allow it to work.

Here is an example:

```
public class Table
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Chair> Chairs { get; set; }

    public Table()
    {
        Chairs = new List<Chair>();
    }
}

public class Chair
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Table Table { get; set; }
}

public class ChairBindModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TableID { get; set; }
}

public class ChairManager
{
    public Chair addChair(ChairBindModel model)
    {
        Chair toAdd = new Chair()
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            TableID = model.TableID  // how can i do this.. instead of querying database for table
        };

        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            context.Chairs.Add(toAdd);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is descriptive enough... thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways, however...
If you declare *virtual* the Table property in your Chair class, you ensure that the table is lazy loaded. Or leave the virtual keyword if you want eager loading.

```
public virtual Table Table { get;set; }
```

Then, if you want to "link" your two objects, you have to put the entity framework magic words :D
In your Chair class:

```
public int TableId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("TableId")]
public virtual Table Table { get; set; }
```

Check [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) for an explanation.